# undefined method `friendships' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fdd1adb7a00> Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many

I´m learning Rails by building an App. My app was working fine until I added this code to my users_controller.rb

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user = User.order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)

end

def compare
 if current_user.profile    
   @users = User.find_by(id: params[:to].to_i) if params[:to]

    @paper_weight_total_user = @users.papers.sum(:paper_weight) 
  else
    redirect_to user_path
  end
end
```

I added this to my users_controller because current user is supposed to be able to compare his data to his friends data if he hits the "Compare data" button(shown below)

```
    <h4> <%= current_user.profile.name%> Friends</h4>
         <ul>
           <% @user.friendships.each do |friendship| %>
           <li>
            <%= link_to user_profile_path(friendship.friend), :method => :get do %>
              <%= friendship.friend.profile.name %>
              (<%= link_to "Remove", friendship, :method => :delete %>)
              <%= link_to friendship do %>

              <%= link_to 'Send message', new_message_path(to: friendship.friend.id), class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs' %> 

              <%= link_to friendship do %>

              <%= link_to 'compare data', compare_friends_path(to: friendship.friend.id), class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs' %>
              <% end %>
          <% end %>
          <% end %>
          <% end %>
          </li>
         </ul>
```

The compare_friends_path worked I was able to compare my data to the selected friend data but when I want to direct back to "My page" the app gives me this error:

```
undefined method `friendships' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fdd1adb7a00>
```

And says that this line of code (the do loop) is causing the error:

```
  <% @user.friendships.each do |friendship| %>
```

my user.rb model has

```
has_many :friendships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :friends, through: :friendships
```

and my friendship.rb model has

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'User'
belongs_to :profile
```

I´ve been trying to figure out why this is happening now after I added the compare option but I´m out of luck.... Can anyone here help me out or give me asuggestion to solve this.

Thanks in advance
Dadi

Comment: can you post the controller action that defines `@user`?

Comment: hi @akz92 I edited the post, now it has the show action in the users_controller.rb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
undefined method `friendships' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fdd1adb7a00>
```

According to this error message, your `@user` object is a `ActiveRecord_Relation` object and not an instance of `User` class, hence you get the error.

According to your model setup, you can get the `friendships` for a particular user by using: `@user.friendships` but this `@user` has to be an instance of `User` class but NOT an `ActiveRecord_Relation` object.

I think the problem is coming from your `show` method's this line:

```
  @user = User.order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)
```

in this case, `@user` is a `ActiveRecord_Relation` object but not a single user. So, when you call `@user.friendships` in the view, you get the mentioned error.

You may want to rename this to `@users` or something like that that makes more sense as this will return a collection of users.

And, you already have a `@user` definition in there:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

where `@user` is an instance of `User` class.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was helpful

Comment: Glad, I could help :-)

Answer (score 1):

That's happening because the second line of your `show` action is overriding the first, so `@user` is actually and array of Users.

In order to be able to call `@user.friendships`, `@user` must be a single User (an instance of User).

You can check this by using `@user.first.friendships`. This won't return any errors